# Is aiohttp truly asynchronous?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I can't find a straight answer on this. Is `aiohttp` asynchronous in the way that Javascript is? I'm building a project where I'll need to send a large number of requests to an endpoint. If I use `requests`, I'll need to wait for the response before I can send the next request. I researched a few async requests libraries in Python, but those all seemed to start new threads to send requests. If I understand asynchronous correctly, starting a new thread pretty much defeats the purpose of asynchronous code (tell me if I'm wrong here). I'm really looking for a single-threaded asynchronous requests library in Python that will send requests much like Javascript would (that is, will send another request while waiting for a response from the first and not start multiple threads). Is `aiohttp` what I'm looking for?

Comment: Starting a new thread *for every* asynchronous request defeats the point, since you might as well use threading explicitly at that point. However, lots of `async`-like libraries use a *thread pool*. That is, they have ten or twenty threads sitting there waiting for jobs to come in and will just do whatever the next job says. It's far more efficient than spinning up new threads constantly, and can also perform better than sitting on one thread the whole time.

Comment: If your goal in avoiding threads is ideological, you might want to reconsider your ideology. If your goal in avoiding threads is due to lack of thread safety in your business logic, then that makes sense, and I understand why you're asking this question.

Comment: yes, you can run many requests (coroutines) simoultaniously with aiohttp and avoid explicit threads